# Keyboard giving United Kingdom characters despite English (United States) language setting

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, international

I am borrowing a work laptop which runs Windows 10 Pro. I am in Australia. The keyboard does strange things for some characters, e.g.:

- shift-3 gives the pound symbol instead of #
- shift-2 gives " instead of @, and shift-single-quote gives @ instead of "
- shift-backslash gives ~ instead of |

The last one is the worst because I can't find any way to make the | symbol, so I cannot do some bash shell commands I need.

Settings-Language says I am using English (United States), which I think is correct.

Settings-Devices-Typing-Advanced keyboard settings gives me only the choice between "English (Australia) United Kingdom" and "English (United States) United Kingdom". Either setting does the same thing. Or do I need to reboot after changing?

Also the backslash key gives #. Which is good that I can make a #, but bad because I cannot make a \ . I can't find any way to make | or \ , other than go into an editor and cut and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Time and Language -> Region and Language -> Preferred Languages, click on English (United States).

[image]
Then, select Options, go to the Keyboards section and and add US (QUERTY).

You can then remove the UK ones from here as well, by clicking on them and selecting Remove.

[image]

You'll then need to reboot the machine for this to take effect.